# I can't find my www folder inside the amazon ec2 server

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

I have the amazon ec2 server I connected my domain in this server and if I browse the URL it's saying **504 Gateway Timeout** I checked the var folder there is no www folder and I found the folder called home inside I checked the folder there are two folders called **centos** and my folder like **tix** and I created the dummy HTML page and me uploaded into the tix folder and I tried the URL still I'm getting the same 504 gateway timeout error. Please help me to where I have to upload my file inside the server and how to fix this gateway error.

Comment: The server seems to be working as a reverse proxy. /var/www is usually defaulting location for httpd in CentOS. If it is not serving from there, the server might be configured to server from some other directory like maybe from the user's home directory or through some other app server or an entirely different server too. Please provide more information on the technology stack you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed Apache2 or Nginx, go to their config files.
You'll need sudo to edit.

Apache2: /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

Nginx:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

These files should show you where your www root directory is located.

If you are using something like cpanel, you'll find that the home directory contains all of the instances of the cpanel accounts that you created.

If this also fails, I'd suggest creating the directory "mkdir -p /var/www" and restarting the server daemon.